# How to set python bindings for mapnik on a linux machine running Enthought Canopy

Tags: python, ubuntu, enthought, mapnik

I currently use Enthought Canopy to run python.
I would like to use Mapnik, I have successfully installed this on my machine

**In a terminal**

```
mapnik -config -v
```

**results in**

```
2.2.0
```

However

```
python -c "import mapnik;print mapnik.__file__"
```

**results in**

```
an import error showing that there is no module named mapnik
```

I believe this is due to me not setting the bindings properly.  I also believe that the **PATH** variable is correct as other modules import properly, although all of these have been installed through the canopy package installer.

Can anyone help me with a fix, or is mapnik not supported by canopy?
If the canopy team see this, can you add mapnik to the package installer?

Thanks 
Ed

Answer (score 2):

you probably built mapnik against a different python installation. Check the first lines of output when building mapnik to find out the python site packages where Mapnik was installed:

```
Checking for C header file Python.h... yes
Bindings Python version... 2.6
Python 2.6 prefix... /usr
Python bindings will install in... /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
```

It happened to me that the python binary used to run the mapnik scons build was the 2.7.5 while the build process picked up the 2.6 version.
I solved using the ./configure (just use the same options you used with scons.py), make and sudo make install.